# How can I start a new activity when I click on infoWindowAdapter?

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi guys I'm a beginner with Android, but what I wanna do is to start a new activity when I push on my infoWindowAdapter in my map. The code seems to be really easy but it doesn't work, I don't know why. Can you help me? I have declared my new activity (MoreInfoActivity) in the manifest and I wanna call it from the main activity. Below you can find all my "MoreInfoActivity" source, its call from MainActivity and also the declaration inside the manifest. Thank you so much

Call from MainActivity when I push on the InfoWindowAdapter: **[UPDATED]**

```
final Activity thiz = this;
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
/*Nuova chiamata di un activity (scelta perché più pratica e la richiamiamo anche dalla listview)*/
/*************************************************************************************************/

    String nome_luogo = marker.getTitle();
    Intent piu_info = new Intent(thiz, MoreInfoActivity.class); 
    piu_info.putExtra("nome", nome_luogo);
    startActivity(piu_info);

/*************************************************************************************************/

    }
});
```

MoreInfoActivity: **[UPDATED]**

```
    public class MoreInfoActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_moreinfo);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
            String value = extras.getString("nome");
            prendi_informazioni(value);
        }
    }

    public void prendi_informazioni(String nome_luogo){
        View layout = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.immagine_luogo);
        //String nome_luogo = marker.getTitle();

        BuildInfoMatrix printinfo = new BuildInfoMatrix();
        printinfo.Fill_Matrix();
        printinfo.Read_Matrix(nome_luogo, layout);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<!-- More informations Activity -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.findmyclients.MoreInfoActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

**Logcat:** http://pastebin.com/pKuW4LCk

Comment: Ok, so what do you see when you touch that map (window)? I would put some log statements inside that method to see if it even gets called at all.

Comment: @Eenvincible sure, is on my first snippet I pasted you. This: map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that your syntax is correct. The part I'm questioning is `MainActivity.this`. I'm not entirely sure what that means but it may be an instance of the class. Instead, create an Activity variable outside of your clickListener and reference from your clickListener. Example:

```
final Activity thiz = this; /* Needs to be final so you can reference it in inner class */

map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    View v2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_moreinfo, null);
    MoreInfoActivity prova = new MoreInfoActivity();
    prova.prendi_informazioni(marker);

    Intent piu_info = new Intent(thiz, MoreInfoActivity.class);    
    startActivity(piu_info);
}
```

});

As a side note, you should never be instantiating instances of Activities yourself. If you need to pass extra arguments to the activity, attach it to the intent by adding extras. See here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, double[])

For example:

```
  String nome_luogo = marker.getTitle();
  piu_info.putExtra("marker", nome_luogo );
```

and in onCreate of MoreInfoActivity:

```
    String marker = getIntent().getExtras().getString("marker");
    doSomething(marker);
```

The way you're doing it now, even if you don't get the null pointer exception, your argument won't be seen by MoreInfoActivity

Comment: this don't work. I tried to comment this two lines and it show the activity:

MoreInfoActivity prova = new MoreInfoActivity();
    prova.prendi_informazioni(marker);

the method "prendi_informazioni" do something with the layout of the MoreInfoActivity...maybe I have to start the activity then I have to make changes ...is it right?

Comment: Like I said in my side note, you shouldn't instantiate the activity yourself because Android isn't going to use that particular instance, it's going to create its own. NEVER create an instance of an activity. Like it says in the side note, if you want to have arguments passed to an Activity, do so by putting extras in the intent.

Comment: maybe, this is what I need.. :)

Comment: What do you mean by marker? If it's a complex object, you can make it implement the Serializable interface, put that object in a Bundle, then put that Bundle in the Intent.

Comment: the pass of extra values now work properly, now I have to pass the right View...thank you guys you are precious !

Comment: Passing views is frowned upon. You should just use some data to inflate a new view in the new activity.

Comment: @AndrewOrobator LOL ok, I've not explained well. Watch, MoreInfoActivity. After I pass it the name as JoaoBiriba said before, I have to call ReadMatrix that need "layout" that is a View...There I have the problem that I have to pass my view

Comment: Does `View v2` exist before you inflate it elsewhere in the activity? It's just odd that you're creating a view to be passed into a new activity. Why not inflate the view in MoreInfoActivity?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
public void prendi_informazioni(Marker marker){
    View layout;
    layout = findViewById(R.id.immagine_luogo);
    String nome_luogo = marker.getTitle();

    BuildInfoMatrix printinfo = new BuildInfoMatrix();
    printinfo.Fill_Matrix();
    printinfo.Read_Matrix(nome_luogo, layout);
}
```

Is immagine_luogo defined in R.layout.activity_moreinfo?

Comment: Yes it has been defined

Comment: Could you post your activity_moreinfo.xml?